# WebException timeout vs HttpWebResponse timeout?

Tags: asp.net, webclient, httpwebresponse

I'm using the Asp.Net WebClient to create an HTTP post.

The below code has try-catch block around the code which catches WebException:

```
        try
        {
            using (MyWebClient wc = new MyWebClient())
            {
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = _lender.ContentType;
                wc.Timeout = 200;

                return _lender.GetResult(wc.UploadString(_lender.PostUri, _lender.PostValues));
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            return new ServiceError(ex.Status.ToString());
        }
```

The main exceptions I'm looking for are timeouts. I've extended WebClient to allow me to set the timeout.

When I set the timeout to say 100ms, an exception is thrown as expected. I can get the WebException status as per the example (it returns "timeout"), however, I want to return status codes too.

If I extract the httpwebresponse using ex.Response I get a null value returned, when I was expecting an associated status code.

Why do I not get an HttpStatus.Request.Timeout?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I realise a few things while I search for a solution.

- `WebExceptionStatus` `enum` is not equivalent to http status code that the API you call returned. Instead it is a enum of possible error that may occour during a http call.
- The `WebExceptionStatus` error code that will be returned when you receive an error (400 to 599) from your API is `WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError` aka number 7 as int.
- When you need to get the response body or the real http status code returned from the api, first you need to check if `WebException.Status` is `WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError`. Then you can get the real response from `WebExceptionStatus.Response` and read its content.
- Sometimes the timeout is handled by the caller (aka your code) so you do not have a response in that case. So you can look if `WebException.Status` is `WebExceptionStatus.Timeout`

This is an example:

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (WebException webException)
{
    if (webException.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
    {
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webException.Response;
        var responseText = "";
        using (var content = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseText = content.ReadToEnd(); // Get response body as text
        }
        int statusCode = (int)httpResponse.StatusCode; // Get the status code
    }
    else if (webException.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
    {
       // Timeout handled by your code. You do not have a response here.
    }

    // Handle other webException.Status errors. You do not have a response here.
}
```